# Why do older films and television shows seem to have higher contrast?

Tags: cinema-history

I've always paid attention to how the colors in 1900s video seem to be more "vibrant", in particular the skin color of actors can look blush.

[image: James Stewart and Kim Novak in Vertigo (1958)]

*James Stewart and Kim Novak in Vertigo (1958)*

[image: Cary Grant in North by Northwest (1959)]

*Cary Grant in North by Northwest (1959)*

The reason is likely technical.